# Django method for loading Foreign Key objects

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have model Parent that has a ForeignKey to model Child:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, related_name='parents')

class Child(models.Model):
    some fields here
```

I know that if I have a Parent object and want to get the related Child object, I can simply use:

```
childObj=parent.child
```

If child has not already been loaded, the above will make another query to the DB to instantiate the Child in parent.child.

But, suppose that every time I want to do something like this, I also want to do some additional processing. In other words, whatever method gets called when I invoke parent.child is a method I want to override so I can do additional processing. Does anyone know what this method is or how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `child` property.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    _child = models.ForeignKey(Child, related_name='parents')

    @property
    def child(self):
        child = self._child
        # extra processing here
        return child

class Child(models.Model):
    some fields here
```

Comment: This might work, but it means I can't do filtering on child, only on _child (since properties cannot be used in filters). I'm hoping to identify whatever Django inner method is called when calling parent.child and override that.

Comment: True, and if you're going to be filtering on it, then I wouldn't use the `_` nomenclature. But in any case, once you have your queryset, I'm not sure what advantage overriding some deeper method (if that's even feasible) would have over using a simple property, which is standard and easy to understand. I guess it depends on what you are trying to do exactly.